# Muscle pain because of cold weather?

Tags: injury, pain, muscle-soreness

I recently moved over to a much colder part of the country. It was around 6 months ago. I started my work outs almost 4 months ago. The problem is that I suffer from muscle soreness all the time. I have reduced my work out intensity to almost half and I am not lifting any heavy weights. I also do proper warm ups and cool downs but still the soreness happens. Doesn't look like an injury because even the smaller muscles like biceps and triceps get sore within 24 hours of working out and continue to stay like that for 2-3 days.

I have reduced my Protein intake as well. Can that cause the soreness ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.ehow.com/how-does_5754331_can-air-cause-muscle-aches_.html):

> lower air temperature causes the air to constrict and result in lower
>   pressure. The lower air pressure can cause the soft tissue around your
>   joints to expand in response and it infringes on the joints, which can
>   cause pain that radiates into the muscles

Cold weather might also cause muscle soreness indirectly. First of all, you're more likely to get sick. With sickness comes fever, and with fever comes inflammation.  When it's cold out, you're also less active, and inactivity itself may also cause your muscles to be stiff. You said you've reduced your exercise intensity to about half... are you still exercising 3+ times a week? If not, maybe the lack of exercise is what's causing it. And if your muscles are stiff, they're more likely to be sore when you do exercise (even if you do warm up).

Comment: Hi Lauren, thanks for the answer. I still try to exercise atleast 5 times a week but I have to skip some times because of previous days soreness. Also I agree with you warming up and exercising sore muscles makes matter worse.

Comment: If you're exercising 5 times a week, then it's definitely not because of lack of exercise...maybe it is because of the cold air/sickness. How cold is it where you live? Do you think you might  be sick? Maybe your body is just having a hard time adjusting.

Comment: I moved to a location with temperatures around 15-25 decress celsius but it seems my problem might be because of increased TSH :-( .

Answer (score 2):

This isn't and exact match for your question about protein, but post-workout protein appears to reduce muscle soreness: [Postexercise protein supplementation improves health and muscle soreness during basic military training in marine recruits](http://jap.physiology.org/content/96/3/951.short)

It may follow that a general reduction in protein could be the cause of your symptoms. It would be easier to test than moving to a warmer climate.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer. I am already increasing my Protein intake and trying to sleep in a heated room. This has caused some improvement, don't know which is working.

Comment: @Geek What is your room temperature in the room where you are sleap? - - Too warm temperature, about 27 - 30 celcius, can also cause soreness indirectly when you body consumes energy to decrease your body temperature. I prefer 18 - 20 celcius as a sleeping temperature.